# Possible combinations of same values in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am looking to find a way of displaying the following output

```
**Name**
Red Small
Red Medium
Green Small
Green Medium
Blue Small
Blue Medium
```

From the following table - PRODUCT

```
ProductID  Name  ProductTypeID. 
1  Red  1
2  Green  1
3  Blue  1
4  Small  2
5  Medium  2
```

This is from the same table, I am having a complete brain fog moment.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(p1.Name, ' ', p2.Name) as newName
FROM PRODUCT p1
CROSS JOIN PRODUCT p2
WHERE p1.ProductTypeID = 1 AND p2.ProductTypeID =2
```